# Upload images in background

Tags: ios, swift3, background-process, ios11, swift4

I am using [DropboxSwiftApi](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) to upload images and pdf files to my dropbox account, I want to give user the ability to select images and pdfs even when he/she has no internet connection, so they are uploaded automatically when internet is available . Which approach would be better to achieve this? is there anything like background upload? Can i add this data to some pool_list so internet is available it will be uploaded. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) to observe your internet connection.
If internet is not available you can temporarily store data in database as soon as internet connection is available you can upload all data to the server

```
    //declare this property where it won't go out of scope relative to your listener
let reachability = Reachability()!

    //declare this inside of viewWillAppear

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
        do{
          try reachability.startNotifier()
        }catch{
          print("could not start reachability notifier")
        }
```

When internet is available this method will be called

```
 func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {

  let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

  switch reachability.connection {
  case .wifi:
      print("Reachable via WiFi")
  case .cellular:
      print("Reachable via Cellular")
  case .none:
    print("Network not reachable")
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.